# Update work item in VSTS using workitemtrackinghttpclient c#

Tags: c#, .net, azure-devops

I have problem with Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi.WorkItemTrackingHttpClient class.
I cannot update workitem in my VSTS because the class send empty body in a http patch request. Am I doing something wrong?

**Test code:**

```
private readonly WorkItemTrackingHttpClient _workItemTrackingHttpClient;
public RestApi(string baseUrl, string pat)
{
    var vssConnection = new VssConnection(new Uri(baseUrl), new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, pat));

    _workItemTrackingHttpClient = vssConnection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();

    var document = new JsonPatchDocument();
    document.Add(new JsonPatchOperation()
    {
        Operation = Operation.Add,
        Path = "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Effort",
        Value = 1
    });

    var workItem = _workItemTrackingHttpClient.UpdateWorkItemAsync(document, 233843).Result;
}
```

**Throws:** VssServiceException: You must pass a valid patch document in the body of the request.

I use Fiddler to analyze the request and found that the body is empty. Weird is that it works in february.

[Raw http patch request screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6STp.png)

Comment: Yes, thank you. That was the problem. :) Now is released new version of Newtonsoft.Json (11.0.2) and it works with it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.1, as I got such error when use Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.1 either. I have submitted a feedback at website below, and wait for response:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/212774/api-that-update-a-work-item-field-doesnt-work-with.html

As a workaround, try to use Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.3 instead.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Newtonsoft.Json has been updated to 11.0.2. Having had the above issue, I updated the package to the latest version and the issue was resolved.